# What's the correct xpath?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-firefoxdriver

The html is the same for the input inside a table.  It is differentiated by the td but that is the line before the input.  I can find the td through `find_element_by_id("col3-month46")` but that isn't where the input is.  How do I write an xpath that finds the td but then goes to the input?

I have tried using xpath (which I believe is how I am going to get to the input).

```
<td _ngcontent-c4="" class="text-center ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" formarrayname="timedoe" id="col11-month44">
        <!---->
        <input _ngcontent-c4="" max="24" maxlength="4" min="0"  name="Monthtime" size="2"             class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" type="number">                    
                                        </td>
<td _ngcontent-c4="" class="text-center ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" formarrayname="timedoe" id="col3-month45">
         <input _ngcontent-c4="" max="24" maxlength="4" min="0" name="Monthtime" size="2"             class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" type="number">                    
                                        </td>
<td _ngcontent-c4="" class="text-center ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" formarrayname="timedoe" id="col3-month46">
         <input _ngcontent-c4="" max="24" maxlength="4" min="0" name="Monthtime" size="2"             class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" type="number">                    
                                        </td>
```

Well when I find it through the ID, it says that it isn't an input field.  If I were to find it through the input tag then with selenium it would only input at the first instance and not where I want it.

Comment: I marked the answer of @Kamal because of the simplicity but Frian response does work as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the `td` element you are looking for and then search for its child `input` element.

So this XPath should work for you:

```
//td[@id="col3-month46"]/input
```

And in Python Selenium:

```
find_element_by_xpath('//td[@id="col3-month46"]/input')
```

Comment: Awesome! I had the xpath correct just didn't know how to get to it's child.  The /input worked tho.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It seem like you want get `input` with a unique id in the `parent`, you can use `xpath` to achieve this. In your case you `input` have `name = Monthtime` and the `parent` have `id = col3-month45`, so please try this method :

```
find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="Monthtime" and ./parent::*[@id="col3-month45"]]')
```

Comment: I tried the other comment (I had the xpath to the parent) where I add the "/input" that does work  but I also tried your recommendation.  It also does work as well.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Check Your Xpath with Chropath Extension When you click on inspect and Select ChroPath You Will See Your Xpath:

**HERE IS THERE LINK:**
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chropath/ljngjbnaijcbncmcnjfhigebomdlkcjo

**HERE IS SCREENSHOT:**
[image]

You Can Also Copy your XPath by clicking the copy button This Extension will give you REL XPATH ~ ABS XPATH ~ CSS SELECTOR

**HERE IS THERE LINK:**

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chropath/ljngjbnaijcbncmcnjfhigebomdlkcjo

AND THIS EXTENSION ALSO FOR FIREFOX HERE IS FIREFOX LINK:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/chropath-for-firefox/?src=search

Comment: That doesn't work since it gives the exact path and selenium doesn't use that.

Comment: it will work especially its work on abs path you can try it you will see your work is going easy

Comment: look at the other responses and the xpath.